# Over Ride Class Within ul div

Tags: html, css

I'm using Dreamweaver's Spy menu with no sub items. I'm using a background image for "not active", another for "rollover" and I'm trying to apply one for "active". I created a class for "active" and applied it to one of the ul items. It's not using the background image for "active". It stays on the "not active" image. If I give the the "active" class a background color instead of an image, it will overlay the color on top of the "not active" background image. I know that the "active" class it working because of this.

The "rollover" is working like it should.

```
<!-- begin navContainer -->
<div id="navContainer" class="navPosLeft shadowRadiusNavContainer" >

<!-- begin MenuBar1 -->
<ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarVertical">
<li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Dental Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Meet The Doctor</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Our Office</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Map & Hours</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- end MenuBar1 -->  

</div>
<!-- end navContainer -->
```

The CSS

```
#navContainer {
background-color: #f0e9e0;
height: auto;
width: 148px;
padding: 10px;
}
.navPosLeft {
float: left;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
.shadowRadiusNavContainer {
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888;
}

ul.MenuBarVertical
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 100%;
cursor: default;
width: auto;
}

ul.MenuBarActive
{
z-index: 1000;
}

ul.MenuBarVertical li
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 100%;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
cursor: pointer;
width: auto;
}

ul.MenuBarVertical ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
left: 0;
}

ul.MenuBarVertical ul li
{
width: 8.2em;
}

ul.MenuBarVertical
{
/* [disabled]border: 1px solid #CCC; */
}

ul.MenuBarVertical ul
{
/* [disabled]border: 1px solid #CCC; */
}

ul.MenuBarVertical a
{
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
/* [disabled]background-color: #EEE; */
color: #333;
text-decoration: none;
background-image: url(../images/vmenuitem.png);
padding-top: 0.5em;
padding-right: 0.5em;
padding-bottom: 0.5em;
padding-left: 1em;
background-position: left top;
}

ul.MenuBarVertical a:hover, ul.MenuBarVertical a:focus
{
/* [disabled]background-color: #33C; */
background-image: url(../images/vmenuitem.png);
background-position: left center;
}

.active {
/* [disabled]background-color: #FF9; */
background-image: url(../images/vmenuitem.png);
background-position: left bottom;
}
```

Comment: Posting your HTML and CSS will speed this up!

Comment: What's the best way to paste the css? It's too large for a small post.

Comment: Just update or remove my sample EDIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS cascade assigns weight or [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) based upon your css selector. It appears in this case that the issue relates to .active (one class) has less weight (or specificity) than the background applied to `ul.MenuBarVertical a` and `ul.MenuBarVertical a:hover`.

Assuming by 'active' you mean the current nav item (not as in a:active) then add more weight to the `.active` style (or add !important). Also, since you are using the same image sprite you should only need the background-position to change:

```
ul.MenuBarVertical a.active {
  background-position: left bottom;
}
```

Comment: click on the big check mark next to this answer (below the 0 with the up/down arrows). Thanks!